# Neuroph: What does maxIterations in a LearningRule refer to?

Tags: java, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2994441/3833669) and was wondering what `maxIterations` in a `LearningRule`refers to. Suppose my `DataSet` consists of 10,000 records and my neural net learns this `DataSet` with a `LearningRule` that has `maxIterations` set to 10. Does this mean only the first 10 of the 10,000 records are used to train my `MultiplayerPerceptron(10, 400, 400, 10)`? Or, does it refer to the number of neurons that are trained at each layer for each record? Or, does it refer to something else?

The API documentation states that it is "maxIterations - iteration limit for this learning algorithm", but at what level does the iteration limit apply? For each record in the training set, each connection weight gets updated once, right? What exactly gets limited by `maxIterations`?

(x-post to [sourceforge/neuroph](https://sourceforge.net/p/neuroph/discussion/862858/thread/f95178b3/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the number of batch learning cycles. So 10 iterations means that it will update the weights 10 times, each time after using all the 10,000 records.